# Facebook browser on iOS: problems with localStorage

Tags: javascript, ios, html, facebook

Localstorage for our webapp (react) behaves strange when the site is opened in the Facebook browser on iOS and android. We have an authentication flow that depends on storing a token in localstorage and reading it. The symptoms we see when our site is opened in the facebook browser (a user clicks on a link to our site on Facebook) is that the auth flow **fails on the first attempt** at login but **works on the second attempt** at login. It appears like the localstorage is asyncronous. At least it behaves differently from other browsers like Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

I have tried to do a setTimeout of up to 700 ms before redirecting after login, but it still fails to read the token from localstorage. 
I am however able to do `localstorage.getItem(key)` immediately after `localstorage.setItem(key, value)` and get the expected result.

Comment: "fails on the first attempt at login but works on the second attempt" sounds like the user doing the first login in a normal browser (the one user opens by themselves), and getting redirected back from Facebook login in another browser – Facebook's in-app browser, which probably has an independent localStorage.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue trying to store tokens in localStorage, I think they're getting lost at some point.

Comment: Somehow I managed to hack something, but I don't remember the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody has problems with localStorage in Fasebook in-app browser, please make sure that you set strings to variables in localStorage (not numbers, boolean, etc.). This is a simple rule but sometimes you forget about it when you don't get errors.

This my code worked in smarty Chrome but didn't work as expected in Facebook browser because the `exp` variable was a number:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("exp", exp);
```

But this code worked well in both browsers:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("exp", ''+exp);
```